# Laravel get many objects in one object

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have to make this JSON response which every product has `colors` and each color has many `images`

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "shirt",
        "descriptions": "lorem epsum",
        "colors":[
            {
                "color_name":"red",
                "icon":"1.jpeg",
                "images": [
                    {
                        "url": "1.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "2.png"
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "3.jpeg"
                    }
                ]

            },
        {
            "color_name":"blue",
            "icon":"1.png",
            "images": [
                {
                    "url": "1.png"
                },
                {
                    "url": "2.png"
                },
                {
                    "url": "3.png"
                }
            ]

        }
        ]
    }
]
```

**How can I make the `colors` using eloquent relationships?**

how many tables and columns with foreign keys should I create?

Comment: are you asking for table or relationship?

Comment: You can consider this statement for your problem solution, **A Product `hasmany` colors, a color `hasMany` images and a image `belongsTo` a color**, based on these facts write your models with appropriate logic

Comment: @techguru then how can I call them?

Comment: @DilipHirapara table and relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you've to make three tables

> 1. products -> Product.php(Model name)

- id
- name
- descriptions
- created_at
- updated_at

> 2. colors -> **Color.php**(Model name)

- id
- product_id
- color_name
- created_at
- updated_at

> 3) images -> Image(Model name)

- id
- color_id
- url
- created_at
- updated_at

Three model with relationship.

**Product.php** Model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = "products";

    //get colors
    public function colors(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Color','product_id','id');
    }
}
```

**Color.php** Model

```
class Color extends Model
{
    protected $table = "colors";

    //get product
    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product','product_id','id');
    }

    //get images
    public function images(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image','color_id','id');
    }
}
```

**Image.php** Model

```
class Color extends Model
{
    protected $table = "images";

    //get color
    public function color(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Color','color_id','id');
    }

}
```

Now from product model you can access this colors and images

**Controller**

```
$products = App\Product::with('colors.images')->get();
return \Response::json($products->toArray());
```